# Bayesian approach to trend detection in non-parametric data

Tags: time-series, bayesian, nonparametric

I have a series of data points, and I want to see how much evidence there is that the points are getting bigger over time. The data themselves are counts, but for various reasons I don't want to build a model of this as a Poisson process with potentially changing lambda. I'd like to only look at order statistics.

I know there are various ad-hock approaches I could take (like randomly sampling pairs of points, and seeing how often the most recent of the two is the larger). However, what I'd really like are recommendations for the best approach to take from a Bayesian viewpoint. In particular, I'd like an approach that can continue to evaluate new data points as they come in, continually updating prior beliefs about the strength of the trend. Implicit in this, obviously, is some kind of non-parametric measure of the strength of the trend, so it seems I'm asking for a suggestion for that as well. Hopefully you can excuse the two-fer on account of the clear dependency between the metric and the approach.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that (at least) one site user is giving this question some thought. I'll try out some ideas and let you know if I find anything that looks like it might work.

Comment: actually there's one obvious candidate for the metric: the [Spearman rank correlation coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman's_rank_correlation_coefficient). From the Bayesian perspective, the issue is what, exactly, to do with it.